# Master Stream SubPup Retry?

Tags: javascript, events

I have a basic stream which allow my modules to subscribe to certain message types and to publish messages. Each message currently has a type, and the associated data.

When a module fails accepting a message, I need to restart that module and try to send it the message when it's restarted. However, each message might have multiple subscribers but only one fails. I'm having trouble implementing this part.

My current thought is that each message has an array of modules that are subscribed to it, and when it is successfully passed to a module, the module is removed from that array. The core then tries to reload the module, and when it's reloaded, the core will try to pass the message again.

This seems hacky, though. It's adding a lot of data to each message, and if a module stops reacting, could queue up the message stream. Another thought is a white-list instead.. Each message begins with an empty array called "sent", and any module that accepted the message is added to that list. The core then restarts and resends the message to any modules that are subscribed to that message type.

Anyone have any better ways to solve this problem?

Edit: I should note that EVERYTHING is async. Messages published to the stream aren't sent out to a module until that module is idling, reloading a module could take a few seconds. The only instant part is sending messages to a module- The module is required to reply instantly if it can handle the message.